How to create a Top App Bar with a row below inside it
I want to create a Top App Bar with a row below it and make it (top bar + row) hide when i scroll down and appear when i scroll up. I want the row be part of the Top App Bar.
This is a litte test that i have made:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Test() {

    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()

    Scaffold(topBar = {
        CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = "Test") },
            navigationIcon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Settings, contentDescription = null) },
            scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
        )
    }){ padding ->
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(padding)) {

            RowFilters()
            LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize().nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection)) {
                items(100){
                    Text(text = "Item $it")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And this is what i have obtained from that:


As you can see, the row didn't hide (obviously) and the space between the title and the row is too big.
Basically, i would like to have a Top Bar as YouTube has (but with a title and an icon on the left): a smaller top bar with row of filter, that hide when scroll down and appear when scroll up.
This is picture of the Top Bar of YouTube:


Please edit your post and include the code of the little test. That makes it much easier for the people to answer.

@BenjyTec done. Sorry, i forgot to put the code.

Not a problem. I added an answer below, does this address your use case?

EDIT:
Please try to nest two Scaffolds:
val outerScrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
val innerScrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()

Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        Column {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = "Test") },
                navigationIcon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Settings, contentDescription = null) },
                scrollBehavior = outerScrollBehavior
            )
        }
    }
) { padding ->

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(padding),
        topBar = {
            Column {
                CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                    title = { RowFilters() },
                    expandedHeight = FilterChipDefaults.Height,
                    scrollBehavior = innerScrollBehavior
                )
            }
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->

        Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(innerPadding)) {
            LazyColumn(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .then(
                        if (outerScrollBehavior.state.collapsedFraction == 1f) {
                            Modifier
                                .nestedScroll(innerScrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection)
                                .nestedScroll(outerScrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection)
                        } else {
                            Modifier
                                .nestedScroll(outerScrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection)
                                .nestedScroll(innerScrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection)
                        }
                    )

            ) {
                items(100) {
                    Text(text = "Item $it")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:

It's probably not getting much better than that without building your own TopAppBar Composable. With this code, the title will collapse before the filters, and the filters will expand before the title does.

OLD ANSWER
You can't put additional Composables into a CenterAlignedTopAppBar, but in your case it might be enough to add the RowFilters Composable into another CenterAlignedTopAppBar like this:
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        Column {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = "Test") },
                navigationIcon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Settings, contentDescription = null) },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                title = { RowFilters() },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        }
    }
) { padding ->
    //...
}

As a result, the liftOnScroll coloring will also be consistent.
Output:


The problem I have is that if I do that, the topBar height becomes too big. The YouTube top bar is more compact and doesn't take up as much height. Also, since there are two CenterAlignedTopAppBars, when I scroll up, they appear at the same time, that is, the filter row doesn't appear first and then the title row, as YouTube does.

I see. Please have a look at my edited post. Unfortunately, it's not easy to achieve this.

It is getting closer. I add windowInsets = WindowInsets(0.dp) in the CenterAlignedTopAppBar of the inner Scaffold because this bar had the space of the notification bar. The problem i have now is that the FilterRow was a LazyRow and this bar has an horizontal padding that i don't know how to remove. I think this padding could be the padding between navigationIcon-title-actions of the bar

A TopAppBar has a default padding of 4.dp applied in a deeper level, you can actually inspect it yourself in the source code. You can't easily change that. You would have to build your own TopAppBar Composable, you could try by copying over the official source code and modify the place where the padding is applied. This happens on line 2655 in the AppBar.kt file. Alternatively, start with a Surface Composable and then try to extend it by functionality that is used to collapse it on scrolling.
